# Map.prototype.forEach not iterating over Map

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, sails.js

I initialized a Map from the MySQL RowDataPacket array which I get through Sails Model. Then when console log that Map I could see the results but when I iterate over the Map using Map.prototype.forEach it is not iterating. Can anyone please check what I'm doing wrong?

I'm using the following technology.
Web Framework: Sails:1.1.0
Runtime: NodeJs:v8.16.0
Typescript
Javascript: es6
Database: MySql:5.6

```
    import { Currency } from 'typings/finance';

    import sails from "sails"
    //Sails Model
    const Currency = sails.models.currency

    export class CurrencyConverter {
        private : convertionRates Map<string, Currency>

        public constructor() {
            //Get a new Map
            this.convertionRates = new Map<string, Currency>()
        }

        public async inIt() {
                //Get Data through sails model object form MySql database
                const ConvertionRatesFromDB: Currency[] = await Currency.find()
                //Update this.convertionRates Map
                for (let ConvertionRateFromDB of ConvertionRatesFromDB) {
                    this.convertionRates[ConvertionRateFromDB.code] = ConvertionRateFromDB
                }

                //Data shows here :/
                console.log(this.convertionRates);

                //But nothing logs here :(
                this.convertionRates.forEach(() => console.log("Hello"))
        }    
}
```

I expected to log `Hello` in console multiple times. But got no output.

Comment: It was a typing mistake. I edited that. Thanks for your findings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.convertionRates[ConvertionRateFromDB.code] = ConvertionRateFromDB` is not adding an entry to the `convertionRates` map. `this.convertionRates.set(ConvertionRateFromDB.code, ConvertionRateFromDB)` would do this. Your code adds a object property to the map object.

So in the end your map is empty explaining why nothing is logged.

Comment: Thanks for your solution.